# What is the present time in Hinduism?

Tags: time

In kaala, manvantara ,mahayug, etc. 
Calculating these things are proving to be difficult for me.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "present time"?

Answer (score 2):

This is Seventh Manvantara – the interval of Vaivasvata Manu

[7th manvantara](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/manvantaras-mystery-we-are-presently-in-the-kaliyuga-of-the-28th-mahayuga-of-the-7th-manvantara)

We are in the 7th manvantara .
Each manvantara is divided into 71 maha-yugas.
We are in the 28th maha-yuga of this manvantara.
Each maha-yuga is divided into 4 yugas shown below for the current maha-yuga.
We are in Kaliyuga